# How do you use the jsoncpp library with cmake and conan2

Tags: c++, json, cmake, conan, jsoncpp

Having some trouble right now working with conan2, cmake and the jsoncpp library. I've tried to make the jsoncpp a shared library. I've tried using the `jsoncpp/json/json.h` path. I don't want to run the command `sudo apt install libjsoncpp` because that won't allow me to keep this easy to work with cross platform.

The two problems I have:
I don't know if I'm properly linking the library correctly because I'm getting errors like this on build `undefined reference to Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType)'`. The full command script I am running is:

```bash
cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
cd ./build && make && cd ..
```

The second problem is I don't know if I'm importing the library the right way.

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <json/json.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  std::ifstream file("test.json");
  Json::Value root;
  file >> root;
  std::cout << root["title"] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.4)

message("Building with CMake version: ${CMAKE_VERSION}")

project(Yediri)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")
add_definitions("-std=c++20")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
message("Project Name: ${PROJECT_NAME}")

find_package(jsoncpp REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${jsoncpp_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${jsoncpp_INCLUDE_DIRS})

message("FOUND CONFIG: ${jsoncpp_CONFIG}")
message("INCLUDE DIRS: ${jsoncpp_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message("LIBRARIES: ${jsoncpp_LIBRARIES}")


install(TARGETS Yediri DESTINATION bin)
```

conanfile.txt

```
[requires]
jsoncpp/1.9.5

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

Message output:

```
FOUND CONFIG: /home/user/yediri/build/jsoncpp-config.cmake
INCLUDE DIRS: /home/user/.conan2/p/jsonc925d41328bf9d/p/include
LIBRARIES: JsonCpp::JsonCpp
```

Comment: what do you see from those `message` commands?

Comment: Is it this: [https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/455#issuecomment-283921965](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/455#issuecomment-283921965)

Comment: Your files are looking good, but I don't know what commands you are running. Please, update your question with your commands, so people can reproduce your steps. Meanwhile, you can try: `conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing && cd build && cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake && cmake --build .`. These commands worked for me and probably will work for you too. Also, please read how to build a project with cmake: https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/consuming_packages/build_simple_cmake_project.html

Comment: I added the command. It is after cmake finishes and I'm running the make command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what was going on. My version of CMake is older than what conan anticipates. cmake version 3.18.4. Conan expects a version > 3.20. So the fix was to add the following configuration to my cmake command.

```bash
cmake -S . -B build -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/jfehrman/yediri/build/conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091=NEW -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

When I read the output of conan install more closely it advised how to configure CMake for versions earlier than 3.20. That is how I found the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use CMake imported targets like a good citizen, and keep it simple:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(Yediri LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(jsoncpp REQUIRED)

add_executable(Yediri main.cpp)
target_compile_features(Yediri PRIVATE cxx_std_20)
target_link_libraries(Yediri PRIVATE JsonCpp::JsonCpp)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS Yediri DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
```

Comment: Unfortunately no dice with this method. When running the make command in the build directory I get `yediri/main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: json/json.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <json/json.h>`